# How to get product from custom attribute in Magneto 2?

Tags: magento2, controllers, model, custom-attributes

I have a Custom attribute on Product in which i have save a string i want to get count of those products which have same attribute value in Magento 2 using an Controller or Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject the class `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollectionFactory`

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('your_attribute', ['eq' => 'your_value']);
$numberOfProducts = $productCollection->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for that It Works @michael

Comment: Is there a way to get only disable product using " productCollectionFactory " @MichiP

Comment: I think it's not that easy to get a collection of disabled products in a Magento frontend. (It's not like adding another `addFiledToFilter`). However, I found this answer here, maybe it helps you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276854/getting-disabled-products-in-a-collection-for-magento-2-3-1

Comment: Thanks for the link i tried that before but it seems doesn't work @MichiP
will you please look into this question and help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317376/how-to-create-pagination-in-magento-2-using-module?noredirect=1#comment455299_317376

Comment: Is there a way to get next 3 product from productCollectionFactory .
Ex: Like offset type means not show starting 3 product then show product after that .